# Python - Function to iterate through each row in panda dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have data frame with one column and I am trying to iterate through each row of that column with function and have values into new column. 
SO first i tried to run my regex expression on the single string to make sure I get results i expect:

```
# Importing dependencies
  import pandas as pd
  from pandas import ExcelWriter
  from pandas import ExcelFile
  import re

  # Test the pattern on a s string
 s = "64\"X36\"X60\" STACKED STONE AREAWELL BOMAN KEMP"
 z = re.search(r"((\d*[\.|-]?\d+(\/\d*)?)\s*((?:cms? 
 |in|inch|inches|mms?)\b|(?:[\"|\'|\”])|\s?)\s* 
 [x|X]\s*){0,2}(\d*[\.|-]?\d+(\/\d*)?)\s*((?:cms? 
 |in|inch|inches|mms?)\b|(?:[\"|\'|\”])|\s?)" , s, 
 flags=re.I)

 print(z.group(0))
```

And my results are 64"X36"X60" which is exactly what i want to get. However when i apply this in form of the function on the data frame:

```
  def patterns(row):
  return re.search(r"((\d*[\.|-]?\d+(\/\d*)?)\s* 
  ((?:cms?|in|inch|inches|mms?)\b|(?: 
  [\"|\'|\”])|\s?)\s*[x|X]\s*){0,2}(\d*[\.|-]?\d+ 
  (\/\d*)?)\s*((?:cms?|in|inch|inches|mms?)\b|(?: 
  [\"|\'|\”])|\s?)", row["Description"], 
  flags=re.I)

# Apply the function to each row
df["Dimensions"] = df.apply(patterns, axis=1)
```

I get results in format like this:

```
re.Match object; span=(0, 11), match='52"X36"X72"'
```

So I think I am not structuring my function correctly. In the sample test when i add

```
print(z.group(0))
```

it reads the data from the match element only which is exactly what i nead. Anyone can pin point how do i ajdust the function to give me the same results for each row?

I tried adding  .group(0) at the end of the function but this is the error I get once i execute the it with:

```
df["Dimensions"] = df.apply(patterns, axis=1)
```

Error:
   [image]

Comment: add `.group(0)` at the end of your return code in the `patterns` function.
`return re.search(r"((\d ... s?)", row["Description"], flags=re.I).group(0)`

Comment: @ John Jefferson Bautista - thank you for response John. I have tried using that too but i get the error message: "AttributeError: ("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'", 'occurred at index 65')". I just posted full error up in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was thrown because `re.search` returned None, cause there is no matching string in that row. Try adding a condition to somehow return something else if the string is not found, the code below returns "None" if string is not found.

```
def patterns(row):
  s = re.search(r"((\d*[\.|-]?\d+(\/\d*)?)\s* 
  ((?:cms?|in|inch|inches|mms?)\b|(?: 
  [\"|\'|\”])|\s?)\s*[x|X]\s*){0,2}(\d*[\.|-]?\d+ 
  (\/\d*)?)\s*((?:cms?|in|inch|inches|mms?)\b|(?: 
  [\"|\'|\”])|\s?)", row["Description"], 
  flags=re.I)

  return s.group(0) if s else "None"
```